# How to access a Thermocouple signal in PC?

Tags: thermocouple, daq

I'm looking for the way to access a thermocouple signal to use it in my own software.

I suppose that I have to place a data acquisition system (something like this https://www.dataq.com/data-acquisition/thermocouple/) between the thermocouple and the PC. The problem is to find a DAQ that shows the software calls to use it in my own code. I'm seeing that the main part of the DAQs have their own closed software and don't allow to see those calls.

Does anyone know a DAQ that allows this? Or another method to connect the thermocouple and use the signal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be in the computer stored in a register, you don't need hardware

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose that I have to place a data acquisition system (something like this https://www.dataq.com/data-acquisition/thermocouple/) between the thermocouple and the PC. The problem is to find a DAQ that shows the software calls to use it in my own code. I'm seeing that the main part of the DAQs have their own closed software and don't allow to see those calls.

I have never seen a piece of PC DAQ hardware that did not provide APIs for software integration.  That is the whole point of DAQ hardware.

> Does anyone know a DAQ that allows this? Or another method to connect the thermocouple and use the signal?

The company you linked above provides APIs for a number of programming languages for its DAQ hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of companies have these. For example, Advantech (Taiwan) has 10/100 Ethernet modules that are properly isolated.

Thermocouples and RTDs are relatively easy because there are usually no worries about synchronization and timing that you would have with higher bandwidth sensors.

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with arduino (nano to make it small) connected to thermocouple. It will show up as a COM port on the PC, which you can easily access from PC. I did that kind of communication with Python and Java, shouldn't be too hard. If you need more precision, you can connect RS232 serial converter to STM32 blue pill to thermocouple. The final result will be the same - virtual COM port. It has prettier ADC, but needs 3.3V (serial converter can provide that). And you can also program it with Arduino IDE, there's plenty of examples on youtube.